# Why aren't there any Baptist monasteries?

Tags: monasticism

So, why aren't there any Baptist monasteries? Is there some sort of theological opposition, or do Baptists just don't do it?

Answer (score 10):

In general, Baptists have historically [harbored animosity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/23023/what-is-the-historical-and-theological-basis-for-protestant-anti-catholicism) towards anything that smacked of "papistry." Note, for example, John Bunyan's polemics in Pilgrims Progress. Add to that a fear of turning the Gospel into a "work," and you will see that it definitely goes against the grain of traditional Baptist upbringing.

As always, with Baptists, nothing is universal. It's not that we ["hate" spiritual discipline, it's just that it usually doesn't occur to us.](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/6435/1039). The same things that apply to mysticism and spiritual discipline would adhere to asceticism and monasticism too. Often after reading something by Dallas Willard a Baptist might get a notion to have a new "experience," but in the main the historical and theological norms would tend to discount the monastic impulse.

Comment: Why then do Baptists harbor vigorous animosity towards anything that looks like "papistry"? Do Baptists hold the animosity against the Orthodox Christian Church?

Comment: [What is the historical and theological basis for Protestant anti-Catholicism?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/23023)